# How to multiply cells belonging to specific month of a year and company name?

Tags: excel

Here is my input with daily data from 2001 to 2016 for 200 companies:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9byym.jpg)

And the output with monthly data (Here I calculate "Product" in June, 2000 = product of all "(Daily Returns/100+1)" in June 2000:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYR1F.png)

The problem is that I have to enter the formula for each month for each company to compute this. Is there a more efficient solution to the problem?
P.S. Number of days each month/year/for each company isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
=PRODUCT(IF(('NYSE Returns'!$C$3:$C$1000>=B3)*('NYSE Returns'!$C$3:$C$1000<EDATE(B3,1)),'NYSE Returns'!$E$3:$E$1000))
```

This is an array formula so use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just ENTER when inputing the formula.

You can change the 1000 to match the end of your data as I think it must go beyond 1000.  Also, I've not tested it yet so let me know if you get an error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The formula looks almost right, but it didn't work anyway. I have now placed everything on one sheet. You can see that the reference to cells in the end of the formula isn't valid. It seems that IF-function requires some other output of "value if true":
[=PRODUCT(IF(AND($C$3:$C$783940>=B3;$C$3:$C$783940<EDATE(B3,1));$E$3:$E$783940))][1]

I have tried another formulation of it, but it didn't work either for the same reason:
[=IF(AND($C$3:$C$783940>=B3;$C$3:$C$783940<EDATE(B3,1));PRODUCT($E$3:$E$783940))][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO6Pe.png

Comment: Yes the $E$3:$E$783940 at the end should have had the sheet name reference.  The issue appears to be with the AND( as it works OK with 1 condition.

Comment: Found it.  To use multiple conditions instead of AND(... you use (condition 1)*(condition 2).  It should work now.

Comment: [Same problem here. The last reference to cells ($E$3:$E$1000) isn't working: ][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZMVG.png

Comment: Did you remembr to do the ctrl+shift+enter?

Comment: I did. However I could already see while entering the formula that $E$3:$E$1000 cells didn't "lighten up" like other references. I assume it might have connection with the IF-function. I don't think it understands the reference $E$3:$E$1000 as a command.